# Windows installer XML doesn't copy assemblies into the installer

Tags: wix

I have trouble with my installer file. The installer does build without any error but when I try to install it on another computer (which obvious doesn't have have the required assemblies) I am getting an error which says that the assembly couldn't be found. Do I miss something obvious?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="Recap" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Lavahayn Technology" UpgradeCode="6824BC1E-B8AD-4EE0-B3F7-B3E84859B9F9">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="license.rtf" />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Recap" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcuts"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="UninstallerShortCut" />
    </Feature>

  </Product>


  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="Company" Name="Lavahayn Technology" >
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Recap" >
            <Component Id="UninstallerShortCut" Guid="3AE87174-A4B1-4887-8D23-5CC651B0CED8">
              <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct2"
                    Name="Uninstall"
                    Description="Removes Recap from your computer"
                    Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe"
                    Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"/>
              <RemoveFolder Id="INSTALLFOLDER" On="uninstall"/>
            </Component>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuSubfolder" Name="Lavahayn Technology">
          <Component Id="ApplicationShortcuts" Guid="432BC349-14B9-4224-B226-A0C55B25498A">
            <Shortcut Id="RecapShortcut" Name="Recap" Description="Lavahayn Technology Recap"
                      Target="[INSTALLDIR]LavahaynTechnology.Launcher.exe" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"/>
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\LavahaynTechnology\Recap"
                      Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
            <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct"
                  Name="Uninstall"
                  Description="Removes Recap from your computer"
                  Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe"
                  Arguments="/x [ProductCode]"/>
            <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>

    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="LavahaynTechnology.CsharpRecap.exe" Guid="1006A341-572D-45D7-9C0E-6F199C1CF0F5">
        <File Id="LavahaynTechnology.CsharpRecap.exe" Source="$(var.CsharpRecap.TargetDir)CsharpRecap.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="LavahaynTechnology.Database.dll" Guid="872452AA-7075-450B-A28F-90252E9DBB6F">
        <File Id="LavahaynTechnology.Database.dll" Source="$(var.LavahaynTechnology.Database.TargetDir)LavahaynTechnology.Database.dll" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="LavahaynTechnology.Launcher.exe" Guid="C0FEB7B4-87BF-4120-A40C-A5849B84F6DA">
        <File Id="LavahaynTechnology.Launcher.exe" Source="$(var.LavahaynTechnology.Launcher.TargetDir)LavahaynTechnology.Launcher.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="LavahaynTechnology.SDK.dll" Guid="55A6AEDA-162D-4BB7-9F7E-0BFBCB738402">
        <File Id="LavahaynTechnology.SDK.dll" Source="$(var.LavahaynTechnology.SDK.TargetDir)LavahaynTechnology.SDK.dll" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="LavahaynTechnology.ObjectBase.dll" Guid="259F7357-D000-4B97-BA29-F11A176319CB">
        <File Id="LavahaynTechnology.ObjectBase.dll" Source="$(var.LavahaynTechnology.ObjectBase.TargetDir)LavahaynTechnology.ObjectBase.dll" KeyPath="yes" Assembly=".net" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcfwK.png)

Comment: can you paste the exact error message here?

Comment: Yeah don't tell us there's an error then leave us hanging =]

Comment: updated the question :)